# Best practice for managing secrets for ASP.NET Core Web API in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I am currently developing an ASP.NET Core Web API that is set to run on Azure App Service and I am seeking the best practice for managing secrets.

I have a configuration guide from a previous project, and I'm curious if this approach is still considered best practice. In the guide, the configuration setup included a combination of various sources which were layered together to build the final configuration at runtime. It made use of `launchSettings.json`, `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.{ENVIRONMENT}.json`, and `secrets.json` files, along with environment variables and Azure AppConfiguration and KeyVault services.

Here's a summary of how the guide recommended organizing configuration:

1. Secret configuration values, like passwords, connection strings, or API keys, should be added to Azure KeyVault. References to these values should be placed in the Azure AppConfiguration instances.
2. Configuration values specific to a single service should be placed in the `appsettings.json` or `appsettings.{ENVIRONMENT}.json` file for that service.
3. Shared configuration values among services should be added to Azure AppConfiguration.

In my current setup, for instance, I have Application Insights set up and its connection string is located in `secrets.json` while running locally. I need to move this secret to Azure, and based on the guide above, it seems I should use Azure KeyVault. I've seen people creating Key Vault References and then referencing it from AppConfiguration, which seems to align with the approach mentioned above.

Given the practices outlined, I am wondering if that's still the case nowadays?

Any guidance or advice from those with experience managing ASP.NET Core Web API secrets in an Azure environment would be greatly appreciated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-key-vault-references-dotnet-core?tabs=core6x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Given the practices outlined, I am wondering if that's still the case
> nowadays?

Well, based on your scenario and description it seems that for managing your app credentials you are using [azure key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and also, you have your configuration file. Moreover, you have an environment variable that determines the configuration values of your dev and prod environments.

Until now, this is the most appropriate practice. I think you extract application credentials by reading key references from application configuration and getting values from Azure key  vault.

**What's More:**

In addition to the above steps and methods, you can use [Managed identities for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-managed-identities-for-azure-resources). Instead of reading your credentials directly through key-reference of key value you can take the advantage of Managed identities for Azure resources, which allows the app to authenticate with Azure Key Vault using Azure AD authentication without storing credentials in the app's code or configuration. This would certainly add another layer of security to your secret management. Please [refer this official document how to use Azure Managed identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview-for-developers?tabs=portal%2Cdotnet)

**Note:**

The bottom line is, we always consider the following aspects to ensure security safe guard while managing application credentials:

1. Neither the appsettings.json files nor any local configuration should preserve credential information.
2. Configuration values or secrets should environment specific
3. The vault secret shouldn't be made accessible to everyone. It must be decided according to Role-based access control or managed identities

On top of this, I have checked your shared document but, you can check out [new official document for secret management.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does "Managed identities for Azure resources" require Azure CLI setup? Because mine is connected to another project and I'm trying to avoid it because of that. I use Service Principal for the terraform IaC due to the same reason

Comment: No it doesn't requires Azure CLI setup, you can configure on Azure portal or even can use SDK package from Nuget. So, you don't have CLI concern. You can [`check here how can you use  Azure Managed identities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview#how-can-i-use-managed-identities-for-azure-resources)

Comment: Also , [`check this document for how easily you can implement that`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview-for-developers?tabs=portal%2Cdotnet).

Comment: Thank you! As long as it allows me to run the Web API without worrying about the fact that my Azure CLI is being associated with another organization, it's fine. I will try it this weekend and thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, its pleasure to assist you on this.